# Wordpress - Custom fonts stuck on old site root url

Tags: wordpress, font-face

I recently made a website with wordpress 6.4.
I used Twentig as an extension to manage custom google fonts, and set it all up with everything working fine.

I moved the website from its dev subdomain to the main domain, everything worked well, but the custom fonts have completely stopped working.
Looking at the browser console, it keeps on trying to reach the font files from the old url that doesn't exist anymore:
[Screen of the console bug report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UEZU.png)
(wp.kuhnhestale.fr was the dev subdomain, and kuhnhestale.fr is the new url)

I tried everything I could think of, desactivated and reactivated Twentig, switched on and off the "host fonts locally" toggle. I went into every file I could find to erase any mention of the old url, also in the wp_options and wp_postmeta databases, but it still manage to persist somewhere...

Looking at the page source, the wrong url is still called in a style tag:
[Page source screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzV6C.png)

Even though I have updated the theme.json file:
[theme.json screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leGbU.png)

I can't find where the wp-fonts-local is defined to try and modify it.
Have anyone any idea where I can go to fix it ?

Thanks !